# How to handle server responses with AngularJs $resource promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting to learn AngularJs.

Using AngularJs, I have the following factory called "datacontext" which exposes a function for getting a person resource with a specific id:

```
function datacontext($resource, common) {
    var $q = common.$q;
    var People = $resource('/api/people/:id', { id: '@id' });

    var service = {
        getPerson: getPerson
    };

    return service;

    function getPerson(id) {
        var p = People.get({ id: id });

        return $q.when(p);
    }
}
```

and inside my controller I use it as follows:

```
function getPerson(id) {
    return datacontext.getPerson(id).then(onSuccess, onError);

}
function onSuccess(data) {

    return vm.person = data;
}
function onError(data) {
    alert("A");
}
```

My service works by returning the correct resource for the particular id and returns a 404 not found if its not found.

In the code block above, its seems like it always calls the onSuccess callback even if there is a 404 response.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use $q service for promises? What about:

```
    function getPerson(id) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        People.get({ id: id }, function() {   
             //success
        },
        function(){
            //fail
        });
        return defer.promise;
}
```

**Don't forget to inject $q to your service**

Comment: or better still, use the People resource as the service. It already returns promises.

Comment: flup, I would prefer this approach. Thanks.